# ViewModel returning unexpected data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, edmx

In my data first .edmx file I have a partial class Question; I have created a ViewModel to populate my View and submit a form for my Questions.

While my submit ViewModel works just fine, I get a very unexpected return with my get ViewModel. During debugging I can see all of the data I need however the ViewModel is also returning

`{System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Question_AC5369E927D7DA13E53B81D39BBD14BEBF05146E3CC12E147A7CB4C32F869EF9}`

which neither I nor the controller know how to handle. As I said, it also is returning all my other required fields but is breaking on this first odd return.

Has anyone had similar results?

As requested, my View Model;

```
public class GetQuestionViewModel
   {
    public class Question { 
    public Question Questions { get; set; }
    public Response Response { get; set; }
    }
    public GetQuestionViewModel()
    {
        this.QuestionOptions = new HashSet<QuestionOption>();
        this.Responses = new HashSet<Response>();
    } 
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PageNumber { get; set; }
    public string Question1 { get; set; }
    public int QuestionTypeId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> LinkedTo { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Options { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> QuestionRanking { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<QuestionOption> QuestionOptions { get; set; }
    public virtual QuestionType QuestionType { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Response> Responses { get; set; }
    }
```

And the Action;

```
        [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ViewQuestion(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null || id == 0 || id > 13)
        {
            id = 8;
        }

        Question question = db.Questions.Find(id);

        if (question == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(question);
    }
```

Comment: Are you returning the data as JSON? Do you use/need lazy loading?

Comment: I have not yet reached that stage, but I will be. This is my first MVC project and I am still struggling with the basics.

Comment: Show us the view model and if possible the controller code which builds the view model from the EF context

Comment: I begin to think the proxy is not the issue here. Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 0):

What yoy see is normal, is a proxy generated dynamically in order for the Lazy Loading to work. You can try disabling this behavior with:

```
context.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

It can be also turned off globally in EDMX designer.

Comment: Where would I add this; to the view model? Can I then invoke eagerly loading for strongly typed values? Am I mixing apples and oranges in this question?

Comment: I found where to globally disable this in the tt file, but it doesn't appear to have worked and I am still getting the same error?